# Cursor in kernel terminal

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, operating-system, kernel

I'm trying to edit this kernel. c, it doesn't support cursor. I wrote over 25 lines, and it doesn't show more than 25 and I can't go up or down to see the rest. here is the whole code, except the main function.

```
uint8_t make_color(enum vga_color fg, enum vga_color bg) {
    return fg | bg << 4;}
    static const size_t VGA_WIDTH = 80;
    static const size_t VGA_HEIGHT = 25;

    uint16_t make_vgaentry(char c, uint8_t color) {
    uint16_t c16 = c;
    uint16_t color16 = color;
    return c16 | color16 << 8;}

    size_t strlen(const char* str) {
    size_t ret = 0;

    while ( str[ret] != 0 )
            ret++;
    return ret;}
    static const size_t VGA_WIDTH = 80;
    static const size_t VGA_HEIGHT = 25;

    size_t terminal_row;
    size_t terminal_column;
    uint8_t terminal_color;
    uint16_t* terminal_buffer;
    void terminal_initialize() {
    terminal_row = 0;
    terminal_column = 0;
    terminal_color = make_color(COLOR_LIGHT_GREY, COLOR_BLACK);
    terminal_buffer = (uint16_t*) 0xB8000;

    for (size_t y = 0; y < VGA_HEIGHT; y++) {
            for (size_t x = 0; x < VGA_WIDTH; x++) {
                    const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
                    terminal_buffer[index] = make_vgaentry(' ',
                                    terminal_color);
            }}}
void terminal_setcolor(uint8_t color) {
    terminal_color = color;
 }

 void terminal_putentryat(char c, uint8_t color, size_t x, size_t y) 
  {
    const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
    if(y>VGA_HEIGHT){
            size_t index = (VGA_HEIGHT - 1) * VGA_WIDTH;
            for(size_t x = 0; x < VGA_WIDTH; ++x)
    {
   terminal_buffer[index + x] = vga_entry(' ', terminal_color);
   }
    }
    else
    terminal_buffer[index] = make_vgaentry(c, color);}
    void terminal_putchar(char c) {
    terminal_putentryat(c, terminal_color, terminal_column, 
                   terminal_row);
    if (++terminal_column == VGA_WIDTH) {
            terminal_column = 0;
            if (++terminal_row == VGA_HEIGHT)
               terminal_row = 0;}
            else if (c == '\n')
    {
        terminal_row = terminal_row + 1;
        terminal_column = 0;
    }
    }
void terminal_writestring(const char* data) {
    size_t datalen = strlen(data);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < datalen; i++)
            terminal_putchar(data[i]);}
```

i need to have scrolling like the one in the terminal, line by line.

Comment: You have to keep track of the line you're writing on. If you go to a new line from the bottom line (line 25) then you need to move all the display memory (except the first line) one line up.

Comment: do you mean I have to increase the VGA HEIGHT each time i add a new line, and to do so i should add the script in the terminal_putentryat function

Comment: oid terminal_putentryat(char c, uint8_t color, size_t x, size_t y) {
        const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;

        terminal_buffer[index] = make_vgaentry(c, color);
}

Comment: No, instead you need to check `terminal_row` each time you increase it. If it goes over `VGA_HEIGHT` then you need to call a function which moves the contents of the `terminal_buffer` one "line" up.

Comment: do you know a function to move the contents of the terminal_buffer one "line" up?

Comment: The standard C [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) could do it. You probably have to implement it yourself though (there are plenty of examples all over the Internet).

Comment: I found out, the problem was in the curser. I can't move it up or down, any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void terminal_scrollUp(void)
{
    for (size_t y = 1; y < VGA_HEIGHT; y++) 
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < VGA_WIDTH; x++) 
        {
            const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
            terminal_buffer[index - VGA_WIDTH] = terminal_buffer[index];
        }
    }
    for(size_t col = 0; col < VGA_WIDTH; col++)
    {
        terminal_putentryat(' ', terminal_color, col, VGA_HEIGHT - 1);
    }
}

void terminal_putchar(char c) 
{
    terminal_putentryat(c, terminal_color, terminal_column, terminal_row);
    if (++terminal_column == VGA_WIDTH || c == '\n') 
    {
        terminal_column = 0;
        if(terminal_row == VGA_HEIGHT - 1)
        {
            terminal_scrollUp();
        }
        else
        {
            terminal_row++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still not functions. the terminal show blank page,

Comment: i will edit the code and put the whole kernel

Answer (score 0):

The text displayed on the screen is taken directly from the memory. If you move the contents of that memory it will look like the text moved.

So if you move from the second to the last "line" one line up (to the beginning of the display memory are) while setting the last "line" to all zeroes, then it will look like it scrolled.

Something like:

```
char *ptr_to_first_line = terminal_buffer;
char *ptr_to_second_line = terminal_buffer + VGA_WIDTH * 2;  // *2 because of the attribute byte
char *ptr_to_last_line = terminal_buffer + (VGA_WIDTH * 2) * (VGA_HEIGHT - 1); // -1 to get the beginning of the last line
char *ptr_to_end = terminal_buffer + VGA_WIDTH * 2 * VGA_HEIGHT;

// Move (copy, overlapping memory okay) the memory, making appear as it's scrolling
// This copies from the second line to the first line, the third line to the second line, etc.
memmove(ptr_to_first_line, ptr_to_second_line, ptr_to_end - ptr_to_second_line);

// Clear the last line so it appears empty
memset(ptr_to_last_line, 0, VGA_WIDTH * 2);
```

All you have to do after this is to place the cursor at the beginning of the last line.